# How can you run a single RSpec example many times in parallel for deflaking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I have an RSpec test that is flaky. To reproduce the failure I want to run the test hundreds of times as fast as I can. How can I run a single example many times in parallel?

Is there a better way to reproduce a flaky test failure?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you think running your test "hundreds of times as fast as you can" will illuminate the nature of the underlying problem?

Comment: It will not help me know the nature of the problem directly, but it will make it faster for me to debug. Say the test fails 1 out of 100 times. Every time I make a change I have to run it ~100 times to see if the failure is still there or not or get a new failure with new logs and code changes. The faster I can do those 100 runs the faster I get the failure (or don't). Make sense?

Comment: I do this a lot too, I just usually wrap the flaky code in a `begin/rescue` block and trigger debugging once I get a flaky result.

Answer (score 0):

I debug flaky tests by wrapping the flaky code in

```rb
begin
  ... some code that I think is flaky
rescue => e
  require 'debug'; binding.break
end
```

and then running the spec a bunch of times.
e.g.

```bash
# bash
for run in {1..10}; do
  bundle exec rspec spec/some/file/path.rb
done
```

Alternatively you can call the test 100 times in RSpec by wrapping the appropriate context or it block.
e.g.

```rb
100.times do
  it '...' do
    # some test code
  end
end
```

If you have Ruby 3.0 you could try something with Ractor?

```rb
VIRTUAL_CPU_COUNT = Etc.nprocessors
RUN_COUNT = 100

ractors = []

VIRTUAL_CPU_COUNT.times do |i|
  ractors << Ractor.new(i) do |i|
    puts "In Ractor #{i}"
    (RUN_COUNT / VIRTUAL_CPU_COUNT).times do |t|
    `bundle exec rspec spec/some/file/path.rb`
    end
    puts "Finished Ractor #{i}"
    "i: #{i}" # implicit return value, or use Ractor.yield
  end
end

values = ractors.map(&:take)
```

I don't know how to get debugging to work though.

There's also the gem https://rubygems.org/gems/parallel_tests, that might help?